# Override django get_current_site - Work with subdomain

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a Django project with [Sites](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/sites/) enabled.

This project will handle multiple domains and multiple sub-domains.

I have domain.com in Sites table, but when I access sub.domain.com/admin, I get the error `Site matching query does not exist.` If I add sub.domain.com to Sites table, everything works fine.

```
Site.objects.create(domain='domain.com', name='Test1')
# Site.objects.create(domain='sub.domain.com', name='Test2')
```

The problem is that get_current_site(request) does not consider sub-domains and I don't want to create several instances in Sites in order to represent every single sub-domain and domain.

Is there any way I can override get_current_site(request)? I've already built my version but Django itself calls the original one when accessing Django admin and that's a problem.

```
def get_current_site(request: HttpRequest = None):
    from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
    host = request.get_host()
    extract = tldextract.extract(host) 
    domain = extract.registered_domain # removes subdomain
    return Site.objects.get(domain__iexact=domain)
```

Comment: Subdomain is in fact a different site. so they technically should be a different site object. For example: abc.wordpress.com is different from wordpress.com

Comment: but wordpress.com is usually the same as www.wordpress.com, right?

Comment: www.wordpress.com is just a cname of the wordpress.com, so techinically they are still one site or hosted on the same server instance. (they even redirect the www.wordpress.com to wordpress.com nowadays to avoid confusion among people)